# Redirect Non found sub directory link to home page through .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a website like www.example.com and its have some sub directories vol1, vol2,, vol3, .....vol20.

I am facing a issue with Redirect Non found sub directory link to home page through .htaccess.

Suppose when we search/go to any not found url like

```
www.example.com/vol1/05.pdf
www.example.com/vol13/01-39.pdf
www.example.com/vol3/klsdk
```

then it not redirect to home page. i have tried below code in htaccess

```
     # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Options +Indexes
IndexOptions +FancyIndexing

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Comment: You are most likely looking at a rewriting loop. Maybe also at cached results. What does your http servers error log file reveal?

Comment: The last rule redirects everything non existent to `/index.php/non-existent`. Fine so far, but the next round of rewriting will cause trouble: the first rule will rewrite those requests again since the conditions match to `/non-existent`. So a rewriting loop... but one which involves an external redirection, which is why you do not get an http status 500 (internal server error). Only the browser will refuse the game after too many loop iterations.

Comment: @arkascha i have edit my code. Kindly give suggestion

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to help with the vague question. It is unclear what you actually want to implement. Also I have the impression that the code you now updated has next to nothing to do with the code you previously posted.